# Test promise before function is executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Is any way to test a variable value before next function is executed? I want test a code like:

```
dataService.serviceFunction($ctrl.yyy, $ctrl.bbb)
   .then(function(){
      delete $ctrl.xxx;
      delete $ctrl.zzz;
      init($ctrl.bbb);
   }).catch(function(e){
      console.log(e);
   });
```

Now I want check $ctrl.zzz:

```
var promise = dataServiceMock.serviceFunction($ctrl.yyy, $ctrl.bbb);
$t.promise(promise).resolves(function(){
   expect($ctrl.zzz).not.toBeDefined();
});
```

but function init set this object again. Do you know any way to get this?

Comment: You need $rootScope.$digest() to run a promise chain.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but my question is how to run only part of promise chain (before init function)

Comment: You can't. In order to test the code well it should be test-friendly. This indicates a design problem that should be solved somehow. Please, provide the code for all the things that are exist in the question. What is `init`? Where `dataService.serviceFunction` is called?

Comment: Function init get data from server and prepare objects for controller. serviceFunction send data to server. I think that delete $ctrl.zzz doesn't make a sense. Init create new objects and assign it to $ctrl.zzz so this object is "fresh"

Comment: Please, provide the code that has this dataService.serviceFunction . It's not possible to give a meaningful answer otherwise.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have now access to code, but I think it's  markup